# For new line "\n" does not work in python

Tags: python-2.7

For new line I have used `"\n"` in my code . But it generates error . The code is -

```
value1=100
value2=10.10
value3 ="Hello world"

print value1+"\n"+value2+"\n"+value3;
```

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: You need to cast the `int` and `float` types to `str` in order to concatenate them. It's not to do with the newline character

Comment: Error is -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/test1.py", line 5, in <module>
    print value1+"\n"+value2+"\n"+value3
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the other answers here, the simplest change you can do is to use the grouping operator by changing all `+` to `,`

`print value1,"\n",value2,"\n",value3`

Answer (score 2):

`value1` and `value2` are not strings.  you must convert them, `print str(value1)+"\n"+str(value2)+"\n"+value3`

Answer (score 1):

**Best Program with using pep8 format**

```
value1 = 100
value2 = 10.10
value3 = "Hello world"

print "Value1 = %s \nValue2 = %s \nValue3 = %s" % (value1, value2, value3)
```

**OUTPUT**

Value1 = 100

Value2 = 10.1

Value3 = Hello world